# Logic proof using contrapositive

Tags: logic

If n=ab is the product of two integers $a$ and $b$, then either $a\leq n^{(1/2)}$ or $b\leq n^{(1/2)}$. Use the proof by contrapositive method.

The new statement is: if $a>n^{(1/2)}$ or $b>n^{(1/2)}$, then $n\neq ab$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.

I split this into three cases. One, where $a>n^{(1/2)}$, $b>n^{(1/2)}$. I had no problem with this case, multiplying the inequalities together gives $ab>n$, so $ab\neq n$.

Two and three are where I am having problems. In both cases, a statement like $a>n^{(1/2)}$, $b\ngtr n^{(1/2)}$ or $a\ngtr n^{(1/2)}$, $b>n^{(1/2)}$. To demonstrate the problem, which is almost identical for both, I will use the first only.

This statement is split up into two parts: $a>n^{(1/2)}$, $b<n^{(1/2)}$ or $a>n^{(1/2)}$, $b=n^{(1/2)}$. The second of these two is clearly simple to show, but the first not so much.

So, how should I go about concluding $ab\neq n$ from $a>n^{(1/2)}$, $b<n^{(1/2)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately your contrapositive statement is not correct. Your statement is in the form $p \rightarrow (q \lor r)$, whose contrapositive is $\neg(q\lor r) \rightarrow \neg p$. Using DeMorgan's Law: $\neg (q \lor r) \iff \neg q \land \neg r$, our original statement is equivalent to:

If $a > n^{1/2}$ and $b > n^{1/2},$ then $n \not = ab.$

This should be easier!

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Comment: So we only use DeMorgan's law on the or statement as the equality is much easier to negate?

Comment: @Anon I'm not entirely sure what you mean. We use the contrapositive when it's easier to prove than the original statement. In this case, it **is** easier to prove since our premise allows us to assume more, i.e. that $a>n^{1/2}$ **and** $b>n^{1/2}$. When to consider the contrapositive is a whole other story, as it usually involves intuition acquired from solving many problems.